# Canadian citizens, married, considering emigrating to Spain to retire. Is there an EU registration or visa process?

Tags: canada, eu, residency, spain

Information from Canadian expat residents of Spain appreciated.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes.  You'll need a residence permit.

Comment: A residence permit from Spain, or a residence permit from the "EU" organization?  Thanks.

Comment: The EU does not issue residence permits; each member state issues them.  So you will need a residence permit issued by Spain.  You ought to be able to find some relevant information at the Spanish consulate nearest you.

Answer (score 2):

Only Schengen visas and [long-term residency](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32003L0109) are EU regulated, but in both cases the decision lies with the member states.

The only exception is the EU blue card which requires a work contract and relevant degrees.

Spain does have [retirement visas](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/CHICAGO/es/ServiciosConsulares/Serviciosconsularesenchicago/Documents/documentosvisados/retirado.pdf) but it is possible that they prefer to promote their golden visa schemes instead.